# What is the most efficient algorithm in Python to find the highest and lowest values across all data lists and associated titles

Tags: python, list, algorithm, search

In my program there are multiple quizzes. A user takes a quiz, then the title of the quiz and the score are saved to a database. For ease with the example, I'll represent them using Python lists:

```
[['quizTitle1', score], ['quizTitle2',score] ['quizTitle1', score] ['quizTitle3', score]]
```

I’m trying to print out the title of the quiz that a user is weakest on.

So, using the Python list example you see that the user has taken *quiz 1* two times. On their second go they may have got a better score for the quiz than the first. So, I need to get the highest score the user has achieved with each quiz (their best score). Then I need to find which quiz has the lowest, best score.

My current plan is like this (pseudo code)

```
While found = false
  1st = the first score selected that we are comparing with each other score
  2nd = the score we are comparing to the first
  For loop that repeats in the range of the number of lists
    If (2nd < 1st) or (2nd has the same title and greater mark than 1st):
       2nd becomes 1st
       Loop repeats 
    Else:
       New 2nd is the next list
  Found = true
```

But what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Now that you got a pseudo code, why don't you try it?

Comment: Are you looking for a pure algorithm, or a practical approach? It's about 3 lines in pandas, if you are open to it.

Comment: @PeterArk I’ll still try it just seeing if I was doing something inefficient

Comment: @PéterLeéh I’m listening ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary to store the value of each quiz and update its value with maximum seen so far in your list, then get minimum of all values in the dictionary.

```
scores = [['q1', 20],['q2',30],['q1',40],['q2',10],['q2',45],['q1',10]]
d = {}
for s in scores:
  d[s[0]] = s[1] if s[0] not in d else max(d[s[0]], s[1])
print(d)
print("Lowest best : ", min(d.values()))
```

This prints:

```
{'q1': 40, 'q2': 45}
Lowest best :  40
```

Comment: Thanks I’ll try this later

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are open to [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/), then:

```py
import pandas as pd

l = [["quizTitle1", 15],
     ["quizTitle2", 25],
     ["quizTitle1", 11],
     ["quizTitle3", 84],
     ["quizTitle2", 24]]

df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["quiz", "score"])
print(df)
#          quiz  score
# 0  quizTitle1     15
# 1  quizTitle2     25
# 2  quizTitle1     11
# 3  quizTitle3     84
# 4  quizTitle2     24
```

```py
lowest_score = df.iloc[df.groupby(['quiz']).max().reset_index()["score"].idxmin()]
print(lowest_score)
# quiz     quizTitle1
# score            15
# Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks I’ll look into this later when I can. What is pandas?

Comment: @stackuser7 It's a third-party library designed to do mainly data manipulation. I edited the anwer to include a link to its website.

Answer (score 1):

### A **map-reduce** approach:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

scores = [['q1', 20],['q2',30],['q1',40],['q2',10],['q2',45],['q1',10]]

name, score = itemgetter(0), itemgetter(1)

grouped_scores = groupby(sorted(scores), key=name)              # group by key
highest_scores = (max(g, key=score) for _,g in grouped_scores)  # reduce by key
lowest_highest = min(highest_scores, key=score)                 # reduce

print(lowest_highest)
```

Output:

```
['q1', 40]
```

### Explanation

The functions used are:

- `sorted` ([docs/builtin/sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)) to sort results by quizz name
- `itertools.groupby` ([docs/itertools/groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)), which groups results by quiz assuming they are already sorted by quizz;
- a generator expression, to apply a function to every element of a list... here we have a list of lists and we apply the function `max` to every list;
- `max` and `min` ([docs/builtin/min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)), my two "reduce" functions.

The return values of `groupby` and the generator expression are not lists and if you try to print them directly, you'll see a bunch of unhelpful `<itertools._grouper object at 0x7ff18bbbb850>`. But converting every non-printable object to a list using `list()`, the intermediate values computed are these:

```py
scores = [['q1', 20],['q2',30],['q1',40],['q2',10],['q2',45],['q1',10]]

grouped_scores = [
  ['q1', [['q1', 10], ['q1', 20], ['q1', 40]]],
  ['q2', [['q2', 10], ['q2', 30], ['q2', 45]]]
]

highest_scores = [['q1', 40], ['q2', 45]]

lowest_highest = ['q1', 40]
```

### Python's `map` and `reduce`

Two functions which can often be useful in a map-reduce algorithm:

- `map` ([docs/builtin/map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)), instead of the generator expression, to apply a function to every element of a list;
- `functools.reduce` ([docs/functools/reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)), to repeatedly apply a binary function to the elements in a list, two by two, and replace those two elements by the result, until there is only one element left.

In this case, we are looking for the lowest of the highest scores, so when comparing two elements we would like to keep the min of the two. But instead of applying the `min()` function repeatedly with `reduce`, in python we can call `min()` directly on the whole sequence.

Just for reference, here is what the code would look like if we had used `reduce`:

```py
from itertools import groupby
from functools import reduce

scores = [['q1', 20],['q2',30],['q1',40],['q2',10],['q2',45],['q1',10]]

name, score = itemgetter(0), itemgetter(1)

grouped_scores = groupby(sorted(scores), key=name)  # group by key
highest_scores = map(lambda x: max(x[1], key=score), grouped_scores)  # reduce by key
lowest_highest = reduce(lambda x,y: min(x,y, key=score), highest_scores)  # reduce
print(lowest_highest)
```

Output:

```
['q1', 40]
```

#### Using module more_itertools

Module more_itertools has a function called [map_reduce](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.map_reduce) which groups by key, then reduces by key. This takes care of our `groupby` and `max` steps; we only need to reduce with `min` and we have our result.

```py
from more_itertools import map_reduce
from operator import itemgetter

scores = [['q1', 20],['q2',30],['q1',40],['q2',10],['q2',45],['q1',10]]

name, score = itemgetter(0), itemgetter(1)

highest_scores = map_reduce(scores, keyfunc=name, valuefunc=score, reducefunc=max)
lowest_highest = min(highest_scores.items(), key=score)

print(lowest_highest)
# ('q1', 40)
```

Comment: After `sorted(scores)` there's a [simpler finish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72218139/12671057), but I like how the more-itertools version this ended up with. The nested lambdas with the same parameter name `x` btw were a bit confusing, I'd maybe change them to `g` and `q`, respectively. Or, since you use a score-extracting function multiple times, maybe have a `score = itemgetter(1)` once and then use that.

Comment: @KellyBundy I edited to add functions `name, score = itemgetter(0), itemgetter(1)`. I could avoid the nested lambdas by replacing `grouped_scores = groupby(sorted(scores), key=lambda l:l[0])` with `grouped_scores = map(itemgetter(1), groupby(sorted(scores), key=lambda l:l[0]))`, would that be less confusing?

Comment: I'll remember that using `dict` on a sorted list with duplicate keys can be a good idea!

Comment: It really wasn't the nested lambdas but having the same name `x` meaning two different things. That requires juggling two mental models, depending of which scope I'm thinking about. It's not that bad, but I do find it simpler with different names. Now that one is gone, it's fine. Although I'd probably always prefer a genexp over map+lambda.

Comment: A generator expression is much better indeed! And I can use tuple-unpacking instead of `x[1]`, to get the group in the key,group pair. But as a result, my "map reduce" uses neither `map` nor `reduce` :(

Comment: Yes, not having to do `[1]` is one advantage, at least  if you want to use *multiple* of the unpacked values. And yes, I already suspected you're using `map` because of "map reduce" :-). Though if I'm not mistaken, you used `map` in the "reduce" part, so that didn't seem quite right anyway.

Comment: Oh, you're right

Answer (score 1):

A simple one:

```
scores = [['q1', 20],['q2',30],['q1',40],['q2',10],['q2',45],['q1',10]]

d = dict(sorted(scores))
print(min(d, key=d.get))   # prints q1
```

The `dict` function takes key/value pairs, we just need to sort them first so that each key's *last* value is it's *largest* (because the last is what ends up in the dict). After that, the desired result is simply the key with the smallest value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest way using Python functions:

```
lst = [['quizTitle1', 6], ['quizTitle2', 5], ['quizTitle1', 9], ['quizTitle3', 7]]

sorted_list = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])

print(f'1st quiz: {sorted_list[-1][0]} | score: {sorted_list[-1][1]}')
print(f'last on quiz: {sorted_list[0][0]} | score: {sorted_list[0][1]}')
```

Basically you ask the list to be ordered and then you ask for the last value, which is the higher, and the last, which is 1st in the list. However this is not an algorithm.

Comment: Thanks I’ll try this out later. But what does lamda do ?

Comment: @stackuser7 It creates a function that has argument `x` and returns `x[1]`.

Comment: Having a variable called `list` in python is an extremely bad idea, as `list` is also a builtin function. In addition, this code doesn't solve the problem? We're looking for the quiz with the lowest highest score. Your code appears to simply return the two highest scores of all quizzes.

Comment: @Stef changed. Now it should give the last.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using `defaultdict`, from the built-in `collections` module.  In this case, the value of a key we haven't seen before is an empty list; we don't need to check first, we just append.

```
from collections import defaultdict

quizzes = defaultdict(list)

scores = [['q1', 20],['q2',30],['q1',40],['q2',10],['q2',45],['q1',10]]

# populate the dictionary of results
for score in scores:
    quiznum = score[0]
    result = score[1]
    quizzes[quiznum].append(result)  # new key?  we append to empty list
quizzes

# find min score for each quiz
{ quiznum: min(scores)
  for quiznum, scores in quizzes.items()
}

{'q1': 10, 'q2': 10}
```

The defaultdict keeps all of the scores, which is not necessary for the posted question.  But it will let you determine number of attempts, high score, etc.